# JQuery alert when scrolled to bottom?

Tags: jquery

Having an element such as this:

```
<div id="threads-list" style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 200px;">
// Posts
</div>
```

How do I alert() when the user has reached button (or is 10px from doing it)?

This is what I am trying now:

```
$('#threads-list').scroll(function() {
    if ($('#threads-list').height() + $('#threads-list').scrollTop() == document.getElementById('threads-list').offsetHeight) {
        console.log('do');
        }
    });
```

It seems the problem is with .offsetHeight which is returning the same as .height() (both 200px) which is the containers height but not the content inside, I think getting the content's correct height would be the key to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`offsetHeight` is the wrong thing to check. Try this:

```
$('#threads-list').scroll(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    if (el.height() + el.scrollTop() === this.scrollHeight) {
        alert('do');
    }
});​
```

`scrollHeight` is the height of the whole element, including the part that is currently hidden by scrolling.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/caFwW/

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
var container = $('#threads-list'),
    maxScroll = container[0].scrollHeight - container.height(),
    threshold = 10,
    endFlag = false;

container.on('scroll', function(e){
    if ( maxScroll - container.scrollTop() < threshold ){
        if (!endFlag){
            endFlag = true;
            console.log('The END!');
        }
    } else {
        endFlag = false;
    }
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/vXzk3/1/

---

I have used a flag to avoid doing what you want at the end multiple times..